# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

```
onDrop(picture) {
    this.setState({
        pictures: this.state.pictures.concat(picture),
    });
}
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In your constructor have you initialised state `this.state = { pictures: [] }` or do you have something that overwrites `pictures` with null or undefined?

Comment: if you didn't bind your onDrop function then your `this` context is not your component but your function `this` context. or refactor your function to be an arrow function or bind your onDrop function inside constructor or inside call where you invoke it, as (picture) =>this.onDrop(picture).bind(this).

Answer (score 1):

You must init the value `this.state.pictures` inside the constructor. You can setup state directly only inside the `constructor` in any other case use `this.setState`

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t need to implement a constructor for your React component.

The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted. When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.

Typically, in React constructors are only used for two purposes:

Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
Binding event handler methods to an instance.
You should not call setState() in the constructor(). Instead, if your component needs to use local state, assign the initial state to this.state directly in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Don't call this.setState() here!
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Constructor is the only place where you should assign this.state directly. In all other methods, you need to use this.setState() instead.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state.pictures = []
}
```